# Confusing snippet of code that is accessing an array item via a character

Tags: java, arrays, character

I found this code online, and it returns the most common character in a string. At the point indicated below, we have the expression `++charcnt[ch]`. From what I understand, charcnt is an `int[]`, and the elements of any array must be accessed via an integer indicating the index number of a particular element. `ch` is a character, however... I ran the code and there are no errors. Why doesn't it give an error? I understand we're trying to increment the count, but I don't understand how you're supposed to access the array using a character. Any clarification would be appreciated.

```
public static char getMax(String word) {
    if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input word must have non-empty value.");
    }
    char maxchar = ' ';
    int maxcnt = 0;
    // if you are confident that your input will be only ascii, then this array can be size 128.
    int[] charcnt = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        // increment this character's cnt and compare it to our max.
        if (++charcnt[ch] >= maxcnt) {    #HERE
            maxcnt = charcnt[ch];
            maxchar = ch;
        }
    }
    return maxchar;
}
```

Comment: char can be transformed to an int. Have a look at ASCII tables

Comment: `ch` gets promoted to an `int` before the indexing happens, search [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [JLS Array Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#d5e13507)  (**emphasis mine**)

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or **char** values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and **become int values**.

Answer (score 0):

When you try accessing an array of integers with a character, Java will automatically convert the character to its ASCII value.

Answer (score 0):

According to java specification

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may
>   also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values. An attempt to access
>   an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time
>   error.

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/javaspec/5.doc.html#170952